# How can I identify Firestore stream documents by change type in Flutter? Document added, deleted, modified?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

My Firestore stream just shows all changes to documents in a collection, but its not showing whether that change is an add, delete or modify.

```
              StreamQuery
                  .snapshots(includeMetadataChanges: true)
                  .listen((data) {
              
                data.docChanges.forEach((change) {
              
                  print('document changes ${change.doc.data()}');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DocumentChange](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentChange-class.html) has a property called [type](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentChange/type.html) that will tell you what you want:

```
data.docChanges.forEach((change) {
  print('${change.type}: ${change.doc.data()}');
})
```

Comment: Got it.  Thanks.  Don't know why I had trouble finding that!

Comment: I'm also getting duplicate copies.   Is that likely because I have my StreamQuery in a widget build and it's getting rebuilt?  How would I avoid that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Please post a new question along with a more details description of what's not working the way you expect, along with the code and data you're working with.

Comment: That's fair.   Here is a link to the new question if you can help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65173092/why-is-my-firestore-stream-producing-duplicate-results-on-my-foreach-on-the-snap