# Why is my Firestore Stream producing duplicate results on my forEach on the snaphot?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to act on a specific document change type on my Firestore Stream.  I noticed that when  a doc gets added or removed, I get multiple copies when I iterate over the snapshot.   I'm listening to the stream in my Stateful Widget tree but I'm not calling setState anywhere.  Here is relevant code:

```
@override Widget build(BuildContext context) {
var usersOnStreamQuery =  placeCollection.doc(place).collection('usersOn');

...

body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
              usersOnStreamQuery
                  .snapshots(includeMetadataChanges: true)
                  .listen((data) {
                data.docChanges.forEach((change) {
                  String type;
                  print(
                      'document type ${change.type} on doc ${change.doc.data()}');
                  switch (change.type) {
                    case DocumentChangeType.added:
                      type = 'joined';
                      break;
                    case DocumentChangeType.removed:
                      type = 'left';
                      break;
                    default:
                  }
```

The number of times each gets reported changes, but I noticed I get the same number of each per session.  For example this is for all the same document:

```
flutter: document type DocumentChangeType.added on doc {x: 60, y: 7}
flutter: document type DocumentChangeType.added on doc {x: 60, y: 7}
flutter: document type DocumentChangeType.added on doc {x: 60, y: 7}
flutter: document type DocumentChangeType.added on doc {x: 60, y: 7}
flutter: document type DocumentChangeType.added on doc {x: 60, y: 7}
```

and then the same quantity of below when the doc is removed.  In both cases, I expect only one and can verify in my firestore collection there is only one doc in it.

```
flutter: document type DocumentChangeType.removed on doc {x: 60, y: 7}
flutter: document type DocumentChangeType.removed on doc {x: 60, y: 7}
flutter: document type DocumentChangeType.removed on doc {x: 60, y: 7}
flutter: document type DocumentChangeType.removed on doc {x: 60, y: 7}
flutter: document type DocumentChangeType.removed on doc {x: 60, y: 7}
```

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint or a print statement to the second line of the build function, because I think this is a case of the build function getting called multiple times, not an issue of multiple documents in the snapshot. The build function print statement will confirm this

Comment: @FemiAdegoke, it was a good thought but added the breakpoint and still getting several dupes for 1 break when adding.  When get several removed types, it doesn't even hit the break at start of widget.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried printing `data` before the call to `forEach` to ensure that you are receiving duplicate notifications and not simply one notification being printed due to multiple `build` calls?

Comment: @Lee3, good suggestion.   I am getting multiple `Instance of 'QuerySnapshot` when printing before `data` before `forEach`.   Does this mean it definitely has to do with Widget rebuild?   How can I prevent multiple streams in this case?   I begin listening to the stream in my Widget because I want to display data based on the stream.  Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: That's what it is. You are creating a listener on each build call. Use a StreamBuilder.